# Reading a specific line from a csv file and letting the line vary

Tags: c#, csv

I need to take 1 line from a CSV file and need the line number to be able to vary. I can make an int, double, string etc. and I can change the value from an outer program easily but I don't know how make a file reader script take one of those as the input for the line number.

```
        string GetLine(string lineresults, int LineNumber)
    {
      using (var sr = new StreamReader(lineresults)) {
        for (int i = 1; i < line; i++)
          sr.ReadLine();
        return sr.ReadLine();
      }
    }
```

And I get errors on the GetLine part for semicolons and closeparens expected

Comment: `var lines = File.ReadAllLines(...)` then you can access `lines[line_number - 1]`

Comment: ...or, if you don't want to read the whole file (say, because it's large), use a `StreamReader` to read and discard the first `line_number - 1` lines and then read and keep line `line_number`.

Comment: ... or using Linq `lines.Skip(line_number - 1).Take(1);`

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want random access you can read all lines and store them in an array, so [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (remember that your variable `LineNumber` starts at 0):

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile);
string line = allLines[LineNumber]; // error if less lines, check allLines.Length
```

Another more efficient approach is to use [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which lazy loads the lines, then use `Enumerable.ElementAt` or [`ElementAtOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb494386%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to access the line number:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(pathToFile);
string line = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(LineNumber); // null if there are less lines
```

It is worth noting that it  reads the file until the line number or the end of the file was reached.

MSDN:

> The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use
>   ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before
>   the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must
>   wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access
>   the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files,
>   ReadLines can be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

As @Alex K commented simply read all the lines into an Array and then get the line you are after.

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines( filename);
var line = lines[ lineIndex ];
```

Answer (score 0):

This NuGet package is super-duper helpful for working with CSVs. You can grab individual lines from it, and individual columns by either name or index. Check out info here:

```
[Josh Close - CsvHelper][1]
```